# outputStream write method in Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, httprequest, outputstream

I'm building an app for a company that communicates with MySQL database, I'm trying to send a new entry to the server, but I can't get the `outputstream` `write` method to work, I know there's an error but I can't seem to find a solution

Here's my code:

```
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new OutputStream() {
                @Override
                public void write(int b) throws IOException {

                    Log.e("Car DetailStream Writer","outputStreamWriter write method called");

                    try {
                        int isLargeAsInt = car.isLarge() ? 1 : 0;
                        int isDieselAsInt = car.isDiesel() ? 1 : 0;
                        Log.e("Car Details Write Data",car.getCarModel());
                        writeData =
                                URLEncoder.encode("carModel", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(car.getCarModel(), "UTF-8") + "&" +
                                        URLEncoder.encode("carYear", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(car.getYear(), "UTF-8") + "&" +
                                        URLEncoder.encode("carPlate", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(car.getPlateNumber(), "UTF-8") + "&" +
                                        URLEncoder.encode("isLarge", "UTF-8") + "=" + isLargeAsInt + "&" +
                                        URLEncoder.encode("isDiesel", "UTF-8") + "=" + isDieselAsInt + "&" +
                                        URLEncoder.encode("currentMileage", "UTF-8") + "=" + car.getCurrentMileage();
                        Log.e("Written Data", writeData);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
            Log.d("Buffered Writer","Buffered Writer Created");


bufferedWriter.write(writeData);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
```

and here's the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at com.example.trknil.turknilmanagement.utils.SendUtils.makeHttpRequest(SendUtils.java:124)
```

and this is line 124:

```
bufferedWriter.write(writeData);
```

Can anyone fix the code please and tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: NullPointerException normally means that variable is NULL..

Comment: @RaymondNijland yeah I can see that, but how do I fix it though?

Comment: @brainyJimmy what is your Writer.java at line 157? Are you using string length() method in the code ?May be there is problem.

Comment: @Suresh that's the callback from line 124 in the Writer class, The question is what parameter should I put in the write(); callback to implement the method above